# Conditional Statement produces unintended output

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I am currently experimenting with lists in python and am trying to create a program that will simulate a name game [(click here for reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_Game).

The program asks for user's input and generates a list with each letter of the user's name. It then has to generate 3 new names, each beginning with `"b", "f", "m"`.

So Robert would become:

```
[['b', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], ['f', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't'], 
['m', 'o', 'b', 'e', 'r', 't']]
```

However, in cases where the name begins with the same letter, the first letter is simply removed, so Billy would become

```
[['i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['f', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['m', 'i', 'l', 
'l', 'y']]
```

However, when I run my code instead the output is:

```
[['b', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['f', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['m', 'i', 
'l', 'l', 'y']]
```

Can anyone help? Is there an error in my conditional? Heres my code:

```
# Asks for user name
user_name = input("Enter name here: ")
name = list(user_name)

# Create an empty list that will contain a subsets of lists.
master_list = []

# List containing the first letter of each new name
beginning_of_word = ["b", "f", "m"]

# Creates 3 new names and appends them to master_list
for var in beginning_of_word:
    new_list = list(name)
    # if new_list[0] != 'B' or new_list[0] != 'F' or new_list[0] != 'M':
    if 'B' not in new_list or 'F' not in new_list or 'M' not in new_list:
        new_list.pop(0)
        new_list.insert(0, var)
        master_list.append(new_list)
    else:
        new_list.pop(0)
        master_list.append(new_list)

print(master_list)
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. I tried it out and it doesn't replace if the first letters are same.

Comment: Really? When I run it instead it doesn't replace the first letter if it is B, F, or M.

Comment: I ran it in Jupyter notebook. It works as expected.

Comment: Can you try tunning with input Fred

Comment: You can see what I did [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QJokzjua2ysLTE6TCE5cAOGN4O0C4TPh)

Comment: The first nested list should be illy instead of billy

Comment: Ok, you want it removed?

Comment: Yes. In cases where the first letter of the name begins with either B, F, or M, the first letter should be removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191353/discussion-between-irfanuddin-shafi-and-robert-garza-altuna).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small correction in your condition statement. In your original program, the `else` block was getting skipped. In this approach, we first check for the values that are to be removed and then perform replacement in `else` block of the code. Secondly, the program is case sensitive. You have your characters in Uppercase in condition statement but in your lists, they are lowercase. In the approach below they are all lowercase. If you want it to be robust, you can add `or` or convert the input to lowercase before doing any operation.

```
user_name = input("Enter name here: ")
name = list(user_name)

# Create an empty list that will contain a subsets of lists.
master_list = []

# List containing the first letter of each new name
beginning_of_word = ["b", "f", "m"]

# Creates 3 new names and appends them to master_list
for var in beginning_of_word:
    new_list = list(name)

    if (("b" in new_list) or ("f" in new_list) or ("m" in new_list)):
        new_list.pop(0)
        #new_list.insert(0,)
        master_list.append(new_list)

    else:
        new_list.pop(0)
        new_list.insert(0,var)
        master_list.append(new_list)

print(master_list)
```

The output is

```
Enter name here: john
[['b', 'o', 'h', 'n'], ['f', 'o', 'h', 'n'], ['m', 'o', 'h', 'n']]

Enter name here: billy
[['i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['i', 'l', 'l', 'y'], ['i', 'l', 'l', 'y']]
```

Comment: Please explain what the correction is, why their approach didn't work and why your approach does work. You'll get more upvotes with a complete answer.

Comment: @Soviut I added explanation